# Set Canvas Background, Width and Height with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a struggle, I don't know how to set the background and size of a canvas with respect to MVVM, currently, I handle this only in the View part, and work ok, over this image (canvas) I want to draw some rectangle, but I want to be able to do everything according to MVVM pattern.

```
var bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative));
ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = bmp;
canvas.Width = bmp.PixelWidth;
canvas.Height = bmp.PixelHeight;
canvas.Background = brush;
canvas.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
```

Comment: handle view-related details (like drawing rectangle on canvas) in the view. end of story. view model is not involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view model could expose a property with e.g. the image file path

```
public string ImagePath { get; set; }
```

to which you would bind like this

```
<Canvas Width="{Binding Background.ImageSource.PixelWidth,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Height="{Binding Background.ImageSource.PixelHeight,
                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Canvas.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
    </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>
```

The conversion from `string` to `ImageSource` would automatically be performed by an `ImageSourceConverter` instance in WPF.

---

The Bindings would be simpler when the view model exposes a property of type `BitmapSource`:

```
public BitmapSource Image { get; set; }
```

XAML:

```
<Canvas Width="{Binding Image.PixelWidth}"
        Height="{Binding Image.PixelHeight}"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Canvas.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Image}"/>
    </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>
```